# Use checkbox to trigger saving and clearing cells to another google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a button that activates a macro function that saves data from Sheet1 to database. It works well on a PC. However, to use on iOS it requires a checkbox to trigger macro function. The checkbox is located in (F13).

Below is the code for the 'submitData' function.

```
function submitData() {
        
  var myGooglSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //active google sheet 
 
  var shSheet1= myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); //Sheet1 worksheet
 
  var datasheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Database"); ////Database worksheet
 
  {
  
    var blankRow=datasheet.getLastRow()+1; //next blank row
 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 1).setValue(shSheet1.getRange("B1").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 2).setValue(shSheet1.getRange("D1").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 3).setValue(shSheet1.getRange("F1").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 4).setValue(shSheet1.getRange("B3").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 5).setValue(shSheet1.getRange("B4").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 6).setValue(shSheet1.getRange("B5").getValue());
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 7).setValue(shSheet1.getRange("B6").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 8).setValue(shSheet1.getRange("B8").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 9).setValue(shSheet1.getRange("A9").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 10).setValue(shSheet1.getRange("A10").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 11).setValue(shSheet1.getRange("B10").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 12).setValue(shSheet1.getRange("E3").getValue());
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 13).setValue(shSheet1.getRange("E4").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 14).setValue(shSheet1.getRange("E5").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 15).setValue(shSheet1.getRange("E6").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 16).setValue(shSheet1.getRange("E7").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 17).setValue(shSheet1.getRange("E8").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 18).setValue(shSheet1.getRange("E9").getValue());
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 19).setValue(shSheet1.getRange("E10").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 20).setValue(shSheet1.getRange("E11").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 21).setValue(shSheet1.getRange("E12").getValue()); 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 22).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss');
    
    ;
  
  //Clear data
 
    shSheet1.getRange("B3").clearContent();
    shSheet1.getRange("B4").clearContent();
    shSheet1.getRange("B5").clearContent();
    shSheet1.getRange("B6").clearContent();
    shSheet1.getRange("E3").clearContent();
    shSheet1.getRange("E4").clearContent();
    shSheet1.getRange("E5").clearContent();
    shSheet1.getRange("E6").clearContent();
    shSheet1.getRange("E7").clearContent();
    shSheet1.getRange("E11").clearContent();
    shSheet1.getRange("E12").clearContent();
    shSheet1.getRange("F13").setValue(false);
  }
}
```

I have found this for the function of triggering a response from check box. It works on computer and IOS. 'checkbox.gs'

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var checkBoxLocation = "F13";
  var checkBoxCondition = true;
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == checkBoxLocation) {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var cell = spreadsheet.getRange('Q1');
    if (e.range.getValue() == checkBoxCondition) {
      cell.setValue("F13 ticked");
    }
    else {
      cell.setValue("F13 unticked");
    }
  }
}
```

How do I merge the 'checkbox' into the 'submitData' function creating a button function for PC and a checkbox function for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.rowStart == 13 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    //e.source.toast('Flag1');
    const rl1 = sh.getRangeList(["B1", "D1", "F1", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B8", "A9", "A10", "B10", "E3", "E4", "E5", "E6", "E7", "E8", "E9", "E10", "E11", "E12"]);
    const r = [rl1.getRanges().map(r => r.getValue()).flat()];
    //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(r));
    var dsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let lr = dsh.getLastRow();
    //Logger.log(lr);
    dsh.getRange(lr + 1, 1, r.length, r[0].length).setValues(r);
    dsh.getRange(lr + 1, 22).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss');
    dsh.getRangeList(["B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "E3", "E4", "E5", "E6", "E7", "E11", "E12"]).getRanges().forEach(r => r.clearContent());
    sh.getRange("F13").setValue(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Cooper. However, the macro did not work. I tried changing "Your Sheet Name" to "Sheet1" but that did not work either. It is a very clean formula and much cleaner than mine. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: How did you test it?

Comment: Pasted into new script as a function named checkbox.gs and saved. The run button will not work because of the range undefined error. I have read that is common in an onedit(e) function. I then tested on Sheet1, by putting a 2 in each data box and trying on PC to have some recognizable data.  No, luck. I then closed PC and opened on Google Sheet on phone, and entered a 3 in each box and tried checkbox. Neither all 2 or 3 shows in database.

Comment: This function was setup as you requested to be run by a checkbox in cell F13.  So when you check the checkbox in cell F13 the script runs and the last thing it does is to reset the checkbox.  It works I've tested it.

Comment: Operator error. Many thanks for your assistance.